# How can i create a shortcut list to the controls in my application c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I have an application which contains lot controls (i.e Buttons,text boxs ,etc..). i want the user to assign shortcuts to the controls before i close the application.

P.S: the Application's controls increases as i develop it with time so i want a general code that loop all over the application controls and write them down.?

Is there anyway rather than writing it as a table of the control Vs. the shortcut in a textfile then assigning it to the controls again when i open the application??

Comment: You mena keystroke shortcuts?

Comment: yes i mean the equivalent key on the keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you try to store that Shortcut control values into the registry instead of text file.At run time get the value from registry.try it works.

Comment: so i have to loop over the forms and get all their controls and then add them to the registry?

Comment: You should be able to dientify each specific control by some unique Id or Name